# GSAP in Ionic project

Tags: typescript, ionic-framework, gsap

How can Import the GSAP library into an Ionic project. Just using **npm install gsap** don't work when I import through

```
import { TweenMax, TimelineMax} from "gsap";
```

I use typescript.
Thanks

Comment: npm i gsap; 
npm i @types/gsap ;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need Typings for it. I've used it in several projects (all of them Typescript):

1. Put the GSAP libraries you want to use in `assets/javascripts`
2. Include your file in your `src/index.html` file like this:

   `<script src="assets/javascripts/TweenMax.min.js"></script>`
3. Right after your imports, declare the GSAP objects like this (in all the views you will be using them):

   ```
   /*
     Normal imports here..
   */
   import { LoginPage } from "../login/login";

   declare var TimelineMax: any;        
   declare var TweenMax: any;
   declare var Power1: any;

   @Component({
     selector: 'page-profile',
     templateUrl: 'profile.html',
     providers: [Data, Api, DatePipe]
   })

   export class ProfilePage {
     ...
   ```
4. Use like normal:

   ```
   ...
   ionViewDidLoad(){
     TweenMax.from(".logo", .5, { 
       opacity: 0,
       y: -72,
       ease:  Power1.easeOut
     });
   }
   ...
   ```

Answer (score 1):

Typical import

```
import {TweenMax, Power2, TimelineLite} from "gsap";
```

Get the parts that aren't included inside `TweenMax`

```
import Draggable from "gsap/Draggable";
import ScrollToPlugin from "gsap/ScrollToPlugin";
```

For More information-

https://www.npmjs.com/package/gsap#npm

Comment: Thanks, the problem was the typings that don't work.