# How can I import and use GSAP in an Ionic/Angular project?

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework, gsap

I have a fresh Ionic project ('blank' template).  I have run `npm install gsap --save`.

This is my `app.module.ts`:

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { ErrorHandler, NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { IonicApp, IonicErrorHandler, IonicModule } from 'ionic-angular';
import { SplashScreen } from '@ionic-native/splash-screen';
import { StatusBar } from '@ionic-native/status-bar';

import { MyApp } from './app.component';
import { HomePage } from '../pages/home/home';

import { TweenMax } from "gsap/all";

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    MyApp,
    HomePage
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    IonicModule.forRoot(MyApp)
  ],
  bootstrap: [IonicApp],
  entryComponents: [
    MyApp,
    HomePage
  ],
  providers: [
    StatusBar,
    SplashScreen,
    TweenMax,
    {provide: ErrorHandler, useClass: IonicErrorHandler}
  ]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

And this is my `home.ts`:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { NavController } from 'ionic-angular';
import { TweenMax } from "gsap/all";

@Component({
  selector: 'page-home',
  templateUrl: 'home.html'
})
export class HomePage {

  constructor(
    public navCtrl: NavController,
    public TweenMax: TweenMax
  ) {

  }

  ionViewDidLoad(){
    TweenMax.from(".logo", .5, { 
      opacity: 0,
      y: -72
    });
  }

}
```

But my app is erroring with:

`Runtime error: Can't resolve all parameters for TweenMax: (?, ?, ?).`

What's going on here and why am I getting this error?  I have tried all of the import types from the [npm page](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gsap#npm) and get the same result every time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

GSAP TweenMax doesn't provide definition files by default.

```
npm install --save-dev @types/greensock
```

**Component:**

```
declare var TweenMax: any;
```

Reference : https://medium.com/@mr.frag85/using-gsap-with-angular-6-project-it-works-on-prod-too-9ac036f21487

Sample Stackblitz : https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-tkmxb4?file=app%2Fapp.component.ts

**For Ionic:** please refer [GSAP in Ionic project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45682344/gsap-in-ionic-project)

Comment: Thanks, but this still isn't working.  The article refers to an `angular.json`, which isn't in my project as I'm using Ionic.  I have added the type definitions to my dependencies but it doesn't affect the error message.  I have also tried the `declare var`, without luck

Comment: First Parameter instead of string '.logo', try to pass nativeElement value 'this.testRef.nativeElement'

Comment: It's not that, I can comment out the entire TweenMax call and still get the same error as in my question

Comment: what is the version, you are using?

Comment: Yeah I've read that thread. Doesn't seem right to use HTML to import though. There should be a way to just import properly, it's just a JS library

Comment: Your answer is correct, my issue was that I was importing in `app.module.ts` too.  Removing that got this working perfectly.  Thank you