# Can I use gsap or anime.js with angular 7. If yes, then how?

Tags: angular, typescript, angular7, gsap, web-animations

I tried to implement Gsap using npm install gsap, but its not working. Can you please explain how to use gsap in angular 7. I want to implement animations to my angualr 7 project

Comment: Already answered in my previous question. please take a look. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53024864/how-can-i-import-and-use-gsap-in-an-ionic-angular-project/53024936#53024936

Comment: Thmx! now I have installed tweenMax on Angular. But I am not able to implement few animations..

Comment: This article is mentioned in GSAP's blog about using GSAP with Angular. The article points to Angular 6, but perhaps between versions 6 and 7 things hasn't change all  that much and is still useful: https://medium.com/@philipf5/patterns-for-using-greensock-in-angular-9ec5edf713fb

Answer (score 1):

install gsap and gsap types using npm:

```
npm i gsap
npm i @types/gsap
```

then import tweenMax into ur ts file:

```
import { TweenMax } from 'gsap';
```